# Error after upgrading ecommerce kickstart is breaking my start

Tags: commerce, drush

I'm working on someone else's project that hasn't updated its "Commerce Kickstart" (commerce_kickstart) module in a long time.  After I upgrade it using Drush, the site breaks and I'm left with the message when I navigate to the (development) website:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function commerce_info_fields() in C:\xampp\htdocs\amherstcopy\sites\all\modules\commerce_price_table\commerce_price_table.module on line 560

I googled around for the answer, but had no luck.  Anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: lol, I definitely read the title in my e-mail as "kickstart is breaking my heart." Was coming by to console you. : P

Answer (score 0):

The only reason commerce_info_fields() should have gone AWOL is if the commerce.module file was removed from your server or the module was somehow disabled during your update process. Check those two things: if it's missing, put it back. If it got disabled, try to re-enable it. No clue what about a drush based update would have caused the issue, but I also am unfamiliar with how drush updates distributions. For reference, we document how to update here:

https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install